# In pipenv shell right after installing django: calling manage.py and getting "No module named 'django'"

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I'm following [this](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/create-a-blank-django-project/) tutorial and ran into some trouble. This is the situation:

1. Python 3.6.6
2. Running Windows 10
3. I installed pipenv
4. Created a new virtual environment and entered it with "pipenv shell"
5. I installed django with "pip install django" and it shows up when typing "pip freeze"
6. When I start typing "django-admin.py," tabbing won't result in auto-completion. But despite that, if I run "django-admin.py startproject nameofproject," the correct file is called. Also, if I run python and check the contents of sys.path, it includes path\of\user.virtualenvs\nameofproject\Scripts, which is where django-admin.py is located.
7. If I try running "django-admin.py startproject nameofproject", the correct file is called, but I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
8. To bypass this, I use the absolute path of django-admin.py.
9. Then, I install a couple other packages, make the local.py, producation.py and base.py settings files and requirements.txt
10. Finally, I run "python manage.py migrate" and get this error: "ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"

My requirements.txt file looks like this:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.15
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
Pillow==5.2.0
pytz==2018.5
```

My PYTHONPATH environment variable looks like this:

```
C:\Python36
```

And my PATH environment variable includes:

```
C:\Python36\
C:\Python36\Scripts\
```

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Are you using  manage.py in step 7?

Comment: Clarified in edit :)

Comment: instead of `pipenv shell` followed by your commands, try `pipenv run COMMAND` - for example `pipenv run django-admin startproject mysite` and `pipenv run python manage.py runserver` -- you can also use pipenv to install packages rather than pip

Comment: but I think your problem started at step 6, you should try `python django-admin` rather than `django-admin.py`